# Should I just give up or should I kill myself?

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

I'm a big fan of Rogue, so of course I picked up Desktop Dungeons and got into it.

I've got a couple victories under my belt, and (of course) a couple losses as well.

One thing I'm wondering is about those losses.  Once I've gotten to a point in a dungeon where I know that I'm not going to be able to beat the boss, what should I do? As in, is there any difference?  There's some kind of a score that's calculated when the game is over, but does that score mean anything?  Most importantly though, is there some particular way that I can turn a total loss into less of a loss?

Should I charge the final boss and die gloriously?
Or (as I suspect) is it all a waste of time and should I just hit that `Retire` button as soon as I know I won't win?

Comment: The question titles on this site…

They are glorious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store up gold so that your next character is better off.  So you may want to hold off on spending anything to make a try at what would be a futile boss attempt.

Comment: Definitely collect all the gold and don't spend any, good point there.  Once I've done so though the same gold will carry over whether I suicide or retire, so you're saying either option is equivalent?  Okay.

Comment: Yep, the only carry over between (failed) attempts is the gold, after that it doesn't matter how or when you quit.